# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

No consigo hacer que funcione la session en codeigniter. Cuando añado la librería de esta no parece estar funcionando correctamente ya que me lo detecta como si fuese una clase.

Adjunto codigo.

```
class ControlVisual extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper(['url','html','form']);
    $this->load->model('ControlVisual_Model');
    $this->load->library(['session','errorClass','form_validation']);
}

public function newControl(){
    $newOF = $this->input->post('newOF');

    $this->input->set_userdata('newOF',$newOF);

    echo $this->session->newOF;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Este error suele ser por varias razones:
- Revisa tu autoload, si tienes alguna libreria, modelo o demás que pueda no existir.
- En tu config.php le has puesto una ruta para guardar las sesiones?
- Para añadir un valor a la sesion -> `$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');`